# How to delete Windows 10 version 1809 Clipboard history?

Tags: c++, winapi, clipboard

If I enable [Clipboard History](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-use-new-clipboard-windows-10-october-2018-update) on Windows 10 version 1809, it will then start collecting all copied items so they can be available via `WinKey`+`V` shortcut:

[image]

How can I delete all those items programmatically?

PS. Calling [`EmptyClipboard`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-emptyclipboard) doesn't seem to affect it.

Comment: [`Clipboard.GetHistoryItemsAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.Clipboard.GetHistoryItemsAsync) to get all the history items, and [`DeleteItemFromHistory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.clipboard.deleteitemfromhistory) to delete it.

Comment: Thanks, @RaymondChen. By any chance you aren't planning to write about it in your blog (and convert it from C#), are you?

Comment: I'll probably just update the existing sample.

Comment: @RaymondChen: Sure. Can you post a link?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Clipboard

Comment: @RaymondChen Can [Clipboard.ClearHistory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.clipboard.clearhistory) work the same way?

Comment: @DrakeWu Try it.

Comment: @RaymondChen: Well, `UWP/XAML` is hardly `C++/WinAPI`

Comment: No need for UWP or XAML. With C++/WinRT, it's a one-liner. `winrt::Windows::ApplicationModel::DataTransfer::Clipboard::ClearHistory()`.

Comment: @RaymondChen I appreciate your efforts to push me toward newer technologies, but for this project I need a lower level approach. What COM object is it using internally? I'll try to look up the rest myself.

Comment: You can always do things the hard way if you like. `RoGetActivationFactory()` the `Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.Clipboard` class for `IClipboardStatics2` and then call `IClipboardStatics2::ClearHistory`. This is [the standard pattern for all Windows Runtime static members](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180131-00/?p=97945). Nothing special about the clipboard.

Answer (score -2):

I tried it C. Here is the code......

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <windows.h>
int main(){
unsigned int x = clock();
printf("clearing....");
while (x <= 40000){
x = clock();
OpenClipboard(0);
EmptyClipboard();
CloseClipboard();
    }
}
```

It runs for 40 sec and then stop automatically then all the clipboard history will delete.

Comment: `while (x <= 40000){` this is a terrible way to wait and will consume 100% CPU for no reason