# How to empty clipboard?

Tags: excel, vba, winapi, clipboard

I am trying to extract content from a large library of Word documents using a VBA project in Excel. The machine is Windows 10 64 bit.

I need to use `EmptyClipboard` but I can't get it to do anything - no error, but the clipboard content is unchanged afterwards (I am looking at both the Office clipboard and Windows clipboard and they are both unaffected).

Here is the code I am using:

```vb
Declare PtrSafe Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Declare PtrSafe Function EmptyClipboard Lib "user32" () As LongPtr
Declare PtrSafe Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As LongPtr

Function ClearClipboard()
    Dim ptr As LongPtr
On Error GoTo failed
    ptr = OpenClipboard(0&)
    MsgBox "Open " & ptr
    ptr = -1
    ptr = EmptyClipboard()
    MsgBox "Empty " & ptr
    CloseClipboard
Exit Function
failed:
        Debug.Print Err.Description
End Function
```

EDIT

@drake-wu-msft, I will check out that link - thanks.

In the meantime, further testing following up question from @Rory just makes it weirder.  I used this process:

Clear Windows clipboard (using Windows key + V, clear all)
Clear Office clipboard (Using Clear All option on clipboard viewer)

Both clipboards appear empty and Ctrl+V pastes nothing

Run this (fragment)
...

```
    wordApp.Documents.Open (filePath)
    wordApp.Documents(filePath).Activate  'Breakpoint A 

    Call ClearClipboard 
    wordApp.Documents(filePath).Select    'Breakpoint B
    ActiveDocument.Range.CopyAsPicture '
    imgPath = savePic(ID)                 'Breakpoint C
    ...

    Function ClearClipboard()
    On Error GoTo failed
    OpenClipboard (0&)
    EmptyClipboard
    CloseClipboard
    Exit Function

    failed:
    Debug.Print Err.Description

    End Function
```

Breakpoint results:
A - both clipboards empty
B - both clipboards empty
C - both clipboards contain data from before the initial (manual) clearing - not what was just copied by the CopyAsPicture command

Comment: So you can still paste using Ctrl+V from the Windows clipboard after running that? (It does not work on the Office clipboard)

Comment: Wrong declarations, no error checking.  Return type is BOOL, make that Long in VBA.  A return of 0 tells you that the function failed.

Comment: For windows clipboard, you might want to clear history for it? `EmptyClipboard` did clear the clipboard data for me(nothing appears after Ctrl+V) You could try [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56640652/how-to-delete-windows-10-version-1809-clipboard-history#comment99852501_56640652).

Comment: @Drake Wu MSFT it looks as if that method - or rather the related ClearHistory - is what I need..  but...I get a compile error "Sub or function not defined" - how do I include this in a VBA module?

Comment: I tried to reference the dll in Excel (the dll is somewhere in the Windows directory) but Excel won't accept it.  Does .net use different dlls from Office?  Creating a whole net application seems like overkill for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Empty the office clipboard:

```
#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function AccessibleChildren Lib "oleacc" (ByVal paccContainer As Office.IAccessible, _
    ByVal iChildStart As Long, ByVal cChildren As Long, _
    ByRef rgvarChildren As Any, ByRef pcObtained As Long) As Long
    Public Const myVBA7 As Long = 1
#Else
    Private Declare Function AccessibleChildren Lib "oleacc" (ByVal paccContainer As Office.IAccessible, _
                                                              ByVal iChildStart As Long, ByVal cChildren As Long, _
                                                              ByRef rgvarChildren As Any, ByRef pcObtained As Long) As Long
    Public Const myVBA7 As Long = 0
#End If

Public Sub EvRClearOfficeClipBoard()
    Dim cmnB, IsVis As Boolean, j As Long, Arr As Variant
    Arr = Array(4, 7, 2, 0)                      '4 and 2 for 32 bit, 7 and 0 for 64 bit
    Set cmnB = Application.CommandBars("Office Clipboard")
    IsVis = cmnB.Visible
    If Not IsVis Then
        cmnB.Visible = True
        DoEvents
    End If

    For j = 1 To Arr(0 + myVBA7)
        AccessibleChildren cmnB, Choose(j, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 3, 1), 1, cmnB, 1
    Next
        
    cmnB.accDoDefaultAction CLng(Arr(2 + myVBA7))

    Application.CommandBars("Office Clipboard").Visible = IsVis

End Sub
```

Comment: Rory - um, no.  Ctrl-V pastes nothing.  I was using Windows+V - which did (and still does) show the content still there.  More checking required here - thanks.

Comment: Hans - I get a 1 returned for both checks ie says it has worked - see my response to Rory - after running, ctrl-v is pastes nothing but both windows and office clipboard still show data.  I should have made clear that it is the windows clipboard I need to clear btw.

Comment: EvR - thank you so much for that code - I should have made clear that it is the windows clipboard I am trying to clear - sorry.

Comment: Drake I will check that method out - but following up on Rory's question - further testing makes it weirder:

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to use the .net class in VBA, but I can wrap it with a DLL in C++, The following sample works for me:

```
// dllmain.cpp : Defines the entry point for the DLL application.
#include "pch.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <wrl.h>
#include <Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.h>

using namespace Microsoft::WRL;
using namespace ABI::Windows::ApplicationModel::DataTransfer;
#pragma comment(lib, "RuntimeObject.lib")
//#pragma warning(disable : 4996)

extern "C"  BOOL __declspec(dllexport) WINAPI ClearClipboardHistory()
{
    BOOL result = 0;
    CoInitialize(NULL);
    {
        HSTRING_HEADER header;
        HSTRING string;
        WindowsCreateStringReference(RuntimeClass_Windows_ApplicationModel_DataTransfer_Clipboard,
            wcslen(RuntimeClass_Windows_ApplicationModel_DataTransfer_Clipboard),
            &header,
            &string);
        ComPtr<IClipboardStatics2> ss;
        RoGetActivationFactory(string,
            __uuidof(IClipboardStatics2),
            &ss);

        boolean tmp = result;
        ss.Get()->ClearHistory(&tmp);
        result = tmp;
    }
    CoUninitialize();
    return result;
}
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule,
    DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
    LPVOID lpReserved
)
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Usage:

```
Declare PtrSafe Function func Lib "Path\DllName.dll" () As LongPtr
Function ClearClipboard()
    Dim hr As LongPtr
    hr = func()
End Function
```

Comment: Hi,@nick_b did this answer work for you? Please feel free to [`accept`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it if it did help to you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok - thanks all for your time and answers - confession of stupidity time:

All I had to do was to turn off the Windows clipboard history.  If this is off the clipboard only retains the last item copied which is what I need.  (It also means that you can't see the clipboard contents using Windows+V, which was why I had turned it on for testing.)

So EmptyClipboard only clears the last item if history is on (which is of course is the whole clipboard if history is off).

If history is on then you'll have to use ClearHistory via the dll stuff above - I dodn't get that far before the lightbulb went on.